# Debugging web service asmx silent fail on large amount of data

Tags: web-services, wcf, debugging, web-config

**Quick Overview/Question:**

I have a .asmx web service, which retrieves data from a windows service. Larger data sets are not making it from the windows service back to the asmx service. **How do I find out why?**

**Further description:**

It all works until I try to push large amounts of data from the windows service to the web service. I have messaging in the windows service showing there are always records being pushed back. Large data counts never make it to the .asmx, without any visible error being thrown, causing the web service to wait and eventually times out - I pushed the timeout up to 5 minutes but no difference. **Now I figure it's hitting some kind of limit as 2000 records come back in a couple of seconds and 4000 records doesn't come back in 5 minutes.**

For the record, I realise this architecture is not ideal, but this is more of a learning exercise for me and I would like to learn how to diagnose the exact issue & see the actual error/cause. I believe in the real world I can talk directly with the WCF windows service from .ajax calls. But I seem to be using WCF more and more and would like to learn the skills to diagnose issues better.

I have bumped up a bunch of buffers and times, see the configs below. I guess I'm missing one?

**html client web.config**

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2097151" />  
...
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPointDataServiceContract" maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:05:00" >
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>

 <client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/PointDataService/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IPointDataServiceContract" contract="PointDataServiceProxy.IPointDataServiceContract" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPointDataServiceContract">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PointDataServiceProxy">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

**WCF windows service.exe.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Namespace.PointDataWcfService"
           name="Namespace.PointDataWcfLibrary.ServiceImplementation.PointDataService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Namespace.PointDataWcfLibrary.ServiceContracts.IPointDataServiceContract">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Namespace/PointDataService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <!--name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPointDataServiceContract"
      note since multiple endpoints have dualHttp, we will not specify binding name so both point to the same node-->
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:05:00">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Namespace.PointDataWcfService" >
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - solved, I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else -  I spent a day on this yesterday. The key was turning on tracing - I had tried this before and couldn't get a log file produced but this syntax worked.

I turned on tracing using this block in my web.config. I put it into the web service config and also into the windows service config - changing the filename of each log. Note I also gave 'everyone' full permission the folder it's writing to.

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="sdt"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData= "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\WcfDetailTrace.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This gave me a svc log file I could open using [Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) that was already installed. Firstly the client one didn't shown anything obvious but the server one had red highlighted errors - very easy to spot! The error told me I hadn't declared the maxItemsInObjectGraph for the behavior. Sure enough I was missing the following from the 'Behavior' section.

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
```

Now the data was returned and I was getting the same error in the client, which I could catch in my ajax call. Turns out my second mistake was that I had the behavior declared on the client, but I was not referencing it from my endpoint (behaviorConfiguration="PointDataServiceProxy").

Hope this helps someone else (or me when I forget and come back here!) - it's easy when you can see the error :).